# I'm not sure about this answer

Tags: discussion, answers

Just saw something in the review queue as a late answer:

https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/9669/168

I clicked "No action needed" as it's still a valid answer, however it's simply incorrect.

What should be done in cases like this?

I'm not sure whether to comment, flag or leave it as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Down vote. That is the best response to wrong or incomplete answers.

I would then also comment including information in your comment on why you think that the answer is wrong or incomplete.

I personally will not delete wrong answers, but if you flag it, I will probably also down vote the answer and leave a comment.

The only case where I tend to delete is if the answer is basically a copy of an existing answer.

Answer (score 2):

I also noted the answer, and flagged it for moderator attention, mostly because there is no such file as `templatename/layout/theme.php` in Joomla by default. I also noted yet another answer to the same question, that also struck me as low quality. Not sure why this old (solved) question suddenly is getting so much attention...

Comment: Once someone comments on it, it moves to the top of the list...